# Flow.js uploading in a SINGLE chunk

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, flow-js

I am using [ng-flow](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow) (an angular wrapper for [flow.js](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js) ) to upload images to a server.

JS code: standard with the following option to avoid chunks testing:

```
{ testChunks:false }
```

I prefer NOT to implement on the server a method for multi-chunks upload but simply accept the full file upload as below (i.e. no chunks).

For those interested, my server spring-mvc method is configured to return a Media json object which I parse on the client:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account/images/upload-file", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces =  { "application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public Media uploadFile(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
        @RequestParam(name="accountId", required=true) String accountId,
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException { return new Media(multipartFile, accountId); }
```

How can I get flow.js to upload in a single chunk?

Comment: I'm curious how you will handle larger files without chunks? Most browsers time out HTTP requests at 2 minutes, so any file too large to be completely uploaded in 2 minutes will fail without chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting chunkSize to a very large number (e.g. 10MB) so that the file will be sent in one chunk. Naturally, if the file is larger than that, the issue remains.

E.g.

```
{ chunkSize : 10000000}
```